# Reading serial data of variable lengths and frequency

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, embedded

I am trying to read 2 serial data buffers of variable length and at different frequency.

1. First buffer sent every 400 ms and of buffer size 187.
2. Second buffer sent every 500 ms and of buffer size 216.

With the below implemented code, the buffer size received is always 230 bytes even if the received buffer length is 187 or 216 bytes.

The data bytes read call waits till max 230 bytes are received and hence received data format is not in line with the expected data format.

Below is the implemented code:

```
#define DEVICEPORT "/dev/ttyUSB4"
#define SLEEP_TIMEOUT 400
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 230

int main () {

    int ret = 0;
    struct termios options;

    int fd = open(DEVICEPORT, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );
    
    if(fd == -1)
        cout << "Error in opening the port" << endl;
    else
        cout << "port opened successfully" << endl;

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);

    cfmakeraw(&options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B19200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B19200);

    options.c_cflag |= PARENB;
    options.c_cflag |= PARODD;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS7;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    options.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;//enable receiver
    
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY );
    options.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);

    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 10;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&options)) != 0) /* Set the attributes to the termios structure*/
    {
        cout << "ERROR ! in Setting attributes" << endl;
    }
    else
    {   cout << "couldn't set options .. " << endl;
        tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    }

    ioctl(fd, TCFLSH, 2);

    char buff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

    while(true) {
        cout << "Reading the data : "<< endl;

        int n = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));

        if (n < 0) { 
            cout << "Error while reading .. " << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Read data size :" << n << "\n" ;  
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                cout << buff[i];
            } cout << endl;
        }
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(SLEEP_TIMEOUT));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What serial port settings should I set to read both the buffers of variable length & frequency?

Comment: Are there any headers or footers to distinguish the two kind of data?

Comment: Yes, there different headers to distinguish between the 2 kind of data.

Comment: Then, read the header first and use the information to determine the size of data left to read.

Comment: You mean different _intervals_ yeah? Frequency made me think you had some pulse-width demodulation thing, since frequency is the same thing as baudrate and bps = Hz.

Comment: You misuse the term *"buffer"*; seems like you really mean "message" or "packet".  Is the configuration really 7 bits and odd parity with raw mode?  *"The data bytes read call waits till max 230 bytes are received..."* -- That is just your misinterpretation of what actually happens, i.e. you have nonblocking reads and sleeping.  Study the **man** page for **read()**.

Comment: *"I am trying to read 2 serial data buffers ... First buffer sent every 400 ms ...  Second buffer sent every 500 ms ..."* -- That is described ambiguously. Are there two independent message cycles sharing the serial link (i.e. there is no fixed timing relationship between the two messages)?  Or is there a single **900ms** message cycle of message1, 400ms idle, then message2 and 500ms idle?

Answer (score 0):

Swap out this `int n = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));` for a byte by byte read, at least until you've read the protocol header and size. Maybe something along the lines of this pseudo code:

```
int n = read(fd, header, sizeof(header));
if(n != sizeof(header))
{ /* handle errors */ }

int expected_size = header.size;

n = read(fd, buff, expected_size)
if(n != expected_size)
{ /* handle errors */ }

/* now the first n bytes of buff contain the protocol */
```

You also ought to have a CRC check in there somewhere, because serial data this long isn't to be trusted.

Comment: This code example relies on noncanonical nonblocking **read()** syscalls to magically provide  `sizeof(header)` and `expected_size` results.  No, raw nonblocking **read()** from a serial terminal does not work that way.  Nor is there any assurance that the reads will always be aligned with the message.  This is not robust code.